# Compare Two Table and Update Second Table

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I am new to java and I am working on two table one table is on server side and another one is on client end. What i want is when there is any update in server database it should reflect in client database and when client data not found in server it should get deleted. In below code i fetch both table data.

Server Table 1

```
  ID     |   NAME
  1      |   ABC
  2      |   ABC
  4      |   ABC
  5      |   ABC
```

Local Table 2

```
  ID     |   NAME
  1      |   ABC
  2      |   ABC
  3      |   ABC
  4      |   ABC
```

Expected Result on Local Table

```
  ID     |   NAME
  1      |   ABC
  2      |   ABC
  4      |   ABC
  5      |   ABC
```

Here is my code

```
// LOCAL DATA
ResultSet local_data = stmth2.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM emoticon");
local_data.next();

//SERVER DATA
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection con9 = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mood","root","");
Statement stmt9 = con9.createStatement();
ResultSet server_data = stmt9.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM emo");
```

Is there any standard way to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

If both tables are on different MySQL servers, you might use [replication](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replication.html).

Otherwise, if the local table is not in another MySQL server, you'll maybe find a way to mimic a MySQL server in your Java program. That is, make it useable as a slave for replication anyway.

Or, this should always be possible in your Java program, use polling. Have a thread checking the remote table and synchronizing it with the local one every *n* secs. Of course that's not too gentle on resources though. And there will be a delay until changes are propagated to the client.